# Html5 video lacks anti-aliasing?

Tags: html, video, antialiasing

I'm trying to add video to a portfolio site I'm working on, but it has this choppy quality to it, like it's lacking anti-aliasing.
Or it could be something else.. Does anybody have any clues?

It looks fine when I play it in a video player.

(Open the image in full view to see artifacts better)

Here's the code for the video tag:

```
        <video width="100%" class="videoStyle" autoplay muted loop>
            <source src="video/01-02.mov" type="video/mp4">
            Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>
```

[image]

Comment: what resolution is the video vs how you are scaling/sizing it in the page? how compressed was it in encoding? how does it look if you just access the URL for the video in browser?

Comment: So I tried isolating the issue a bit and found out that when more than one video is playing on the screen at the same time, it get these artefacts. Otherwise it's fine. It is like it is auto lowering the quality when there is more than one video on screen at the same time.